# Are there any ICAO restrictions on naming a taxiway?

Tags: icao-sarps, taxiways

According to ICAO are there any certain restrictions to naming a taxiway? For example:

1. a certain letter cannot be used
2. it cannot have letters that match a parking stand etc.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66845/why-are-oscar-india-and-x-ray-o-i-and-x-not-used-as-taxiway-identifiers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per the [Runway Safety HANDBOOK, First Edition 2014](https://applications.icao.int/tools/RSP_ikit/story_content/external_files/ACI%20Runway%20Safety%20Handbook%202014%20v2%20low.pdf):

> 2.4 Taxiway Naming Convention
> A simple and logical method for designating the taxiways should be developed. The following general guidelines should be followed:
>
> - Naming of the taxiways begins on one side of the aerodrome and carries on to the other extremity (e.g. from east to west or from north to south);
> - The letters I, O and Z are not used, in order to avoid confusion with the numbers 1, 0 and 2. Neither is the letter X used, because it is used to
>   indicate closure of portions of taxiway or runway;
> - There can be no duplication of the use of a taxiway name;
> - A taxiway crossing a runway should be named differently on the two sides of the runway. However, some aerodromes designate crossing taxiways with high traffic volume using the same name on both side of the runway (FAA recommendation); and
> - Number and letter combinations should not result in confusion with runway designations. E.g., if an airport has a runway “4L,” a taxiway designation of “L4” should not be used.
>   ACI recommends that a taxiway accessing a runway should be identified by a code consisting of a letter followed by a figure (e.g. A1, A2, A3 ... A12), beginning with 1 but not 0, from the extremity of the runway and continuing without missing a number.
>   As far as practicable, this type of identification is not used for other, less critical parts of the aerodrome: only one letter is used. The goal of this practice is to warn a pilot or a vehicle driver of proximity with a runway

As it says "general guidelines", they are not absolute rules, but recommendations.

Another source of useful taxiway information is the [Certification Specifications (CS) and Guidance Material (GM) for Aerodromes Design CS-ADR-DSN.](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/2014-013-R-Annex%20to%20ED%20Decision%202014-013-R.pdf) However, while it is very full of very specific information on how to make taxiways (turn radius', width, centerline, markings, shape, etc) it does not speak to naming them at all (that I could see at a skim).

Comment: My airport violates four out of the five guidelines in one way or another...

Answer (score 4):

For reference since your question was specifically ICAO, the FAA has released supplemental guidance in Engineering Brief 89A (superseding EB 89) that is being used throughout the US for planning purposes.

**Webpage:** https://www.faa.gov/airports/engineering/engineering_briefs/eb_89
**Actual Brief:** https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/eb_89A_TWY_Nomenclature.pdf

Comment: Hi Jeff - welcome to Av.SE!  Is there a link you can edit into your answer for the new EB 89A? That would help those who want to follow up on your suggestion. Thanks for contributing, and please do come back often!